# Serve two https hostnames from single node process & port

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, express, https

Is there a way to serve two https sites on the same port from node alone (i.e. without something like nginx)?

I'm using the [https module](http://nodejs.org/api/https.html), for which SSL options (e.g. `key`/`cert`/`ca`) are passed into `createServer`. I tried creating two https servers, each listening to a different hostname, and each with SSL options specific to that hostname:

```
require('https').createServer(sslOptsForFoo, expressApp).listen(443, 'foo.com');
require('https').createServer(sslOptsForBar, expressApp).listen(443, 'bar.com');
```

But this throws an error:

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Another idea is to create a single server rather than two, and to use different SSL options depending on the request's hostname, but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it Possible to Dynamically Return an SSL Certificate in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219639/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-return-an-ssl-certificate-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only do this with SNI so you may want to check for [SNI support with various browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication#Web_browsers) first.

Here's one way to do SNI in node:

```
var https = require('https'),
    fs = require('fs');

// default for non-matching requests
var serverOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('default.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('default.crt')
};

var SNIContexts = {
  'foo.com': {
    key: fs.readFileSync('foo.com.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('foo.com.crt')
  },
  'bar.com': {
    key: fs.readFileSync('bar.com.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('bar.com.crt')
  }
};

var server = https.createServer(serverOptions, function(req, res) {
  res.end('Hello world via ' + req.socket.cleartext.servername);
});

server.addContext('foo.com', SNIContexts['foo.com']);
server.addContext('bar.com', SNIContexts['bar.com']);

server.listen(443, function() {
  console.log('Listening on 443');
});
```

Comment: All modern browsers support SNI. If there are any issues, it will be with down level servers like IIS 7 and down level clients like Python 2.x. By the way, that's a nice example. I'd like to upvote it twice. The [Node.js Manual](http://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_npn_and_sni) should have something that nice.

Comment: FWIW the example pretty much comes from one of node's tests [here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.10/test/simple/test-tls-sni-server-client.js), located in `test/simple`. The tests can be a good reference for examples for scenarios you can't find in the docs or much of anywhere else.

Comment: does this still work?