# I cannot use SNICallback

Tags: node.js, node-http-proxy, sni

I couldn't manage using SNICallback on `createServer`function.
When I try the below codes I get an error as `Missing PFX or certificate + pricate key.`

How can I solve this issue?

```
var fs = require('fs'),
      tls = require('tls'),
      https = require('https');

var certs = {
    "safe.myDomain.com": {
        key: fs.readFileSync('../SSL/safe/private/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('../SSL/safe/certs/cert.pem') 
    },
    "api.myDomain.com": {
        key: fs.readFileSync('../SSL/api/private/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('../SSL/api/certs/cert.pem')   
    }
}

var httpsOptions = {
    SNICallback: function(hostname, cb) {
      var ctx = tls.createSecureContext(certs[hostname])
      cb(null, ctx])
    }
}

https.createServer(httpsOptions).listen(1443, function() {
    console.log('HTTPS server is listening on port 1443')
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options to `https.createServer` must include `key` and `cert` as they are required. Even though that set won't be used if SNI provides a hostname.

See [`tls.createServer`](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createserver_options_secureconnectionlistener) where it marks `key` and `cert` as required. (Linked from [`https.createServer`](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener).)

Comment: Thank you very much!  So, I should give a default certificate for instance for `api.mydomain.com` address. And if the address is not `api.mydomain.com` SNI works and if the address is `safe.mydomain.com` then the address is called. Isn't it?  If so, I'm wondering a user who wants to call `safe.mydomain.com` can pass default `cert`?

Comment: The default as you call it would be for those clients that don't provide a hostname via SNI.

Comment: Really thanks Dan,  I've been dealing with safety protocols of my project for one month. And I'm exhausted...

Answer (score 0):

SNICallback works great in NodeJS.  I use it in production all the time.  Here is a Stackoverlow answer with a detailed example of how to make it work.

[Is it Possible to Dynamically Return an SSL Certificate in NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219639/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-return-an-ssl-certificate-in-nodejs/38862651#38862651)