# Is it possible to hotswap a tls certificate in node.js?

Tags: node.js, ssl

Is it possible to swap out a certificate (say if it gets renewed) without restarting the server in node.js? Any connections that are currently open would have already trusted the server and so don't need to be disconnected, but any new connections need to see the new certificate. I would imagine it should be possible to do this kind of hotswap. Is it possible via the API node.js presents?

Or is there any node https module that allows this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it Possible to Dynamically Return an SSL Certificate in NodeJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219639/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-return-an-ssl-certificate-in-nodejs)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is possible via something called the SNICallback:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/10349#issuecomment-268157842

[I cannot use SNICallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29604697/i-cannot-use-snicallback)

```
var certs = {
    "safe.myDomain.com": {
        key: fs.readFileSync('../SSL/safe/private/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('../SSL/safe/certs/cert.pem') 
    },
    "api.myDomain.com": {
        key: fs.readFileSync('../SSL/api/private/key.pem'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('../SSL/api/certs/cert.pem')   
    }
}

var httpsOptions = {
    SNICallback: function(hostname, cb) {
      var ctx = tls.createSecureContext(certs[hostname])
      cb(null, ctx])
    }
}

https.createServer(httpsOptions).listen(1443, function() {
    console.log('HTTPS server is listening on port 1443')
})
```