# how to override ngnix ssl with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, nginx, ssl

I read this article https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-create-a-HTTPS-server/
which describes how to serve SSL certificate using nodeJS but In my case, I am using a reverse proxy as well, it is possible to override SSL served by NGINX with NodeJS

I have more than a thousand domains and SSL certificate for each domain in a database, I want all those domains to use the same server, that is why I want to serve SSL with nodeJS, if that is not possible, I at least want to serve SSL using the database

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use SSL for nodejs if you already have Nginx with SSL.

```
NodeJS -> (http) -> NGINX -> (https) -> Web
```

Your node SSL will only secure the connection between nodejs and nginx, not to the web

Comment: I have more than a thousand domains and SSL certificate for each domain in a database, I want all those domains to use the same server, that is why I want to serve SSL with NodeJS, if that is not possible, I at least want to serve SSL using the database

Comment: If you want to serve SSL with node JS then you serve nodeJS without reverse proxy. You can create a simple nodeJS  app, that acts as a reverse proxy, that terminates all the SSL connection by serving the SSL certificates. Though it will not be as efficient as nginx reverse proxy.

Comment: What will be the cons of that?

Comment: The only con is you can serve SSL ceritifcates the way you want to. If not you have to search for alternative replacement for nginx since nginx cannot do what you want. There is also a discussion on how to use node to serve multiple certificates here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42522805/multiple-ssl-certificates-and-http-2-with-express-js