# Wakanda, more than one SSL certificate

Tags: javascript, wakanda, ssjs

It´s possible install more than one certificate on Wakanda to secure more than one domain connection?

From Wakanda are served multiple apps under multiple domains in only one wakanda solution/project.
thanks,

Comment: How do you have more than one domain for one project ? There is the possibility to have a `Certificates` folder with its certificat in each project of your solution but it could not be enough in your case.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I only have one project for all domains connections. Every domain is serving different services to the same database. All services shared database structure and most functions and methods. Also, each customer could custom its access domain to the services.

Comment: Did you try to create a certificates on `*.mydomain.com` and have all your services pointing to `mydomain.com` sub-domains ? (e.g. `a.mydomain.com`, `b.mydomain.com`, ...)

Comment: Yes, wildtrack certificates works fine, but only for one domain (and multiple subdomains, of course). My costumers wants its own domains showing its products...

Comment: Could be possible use something similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219639/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-return-an-ssl-certificate-in-nodejs) in wakanda server?