# Serving a secure, self hosted NextJS project with multiple subdomains

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, next.js, tls1.2

Having the following in NextJS' `server.js` allows serving a secure, self hosted server:

```js
https.createServer({
  key: fs.readFileSync('./privkey.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.pem'),
  ca: fs.readFileSync('./chain.pem'),
}, (req, res) => { ... })
```

When dealing with multiple subdomains, what should I pass `createServer` as options?

I tried this:

```js
https.createServer({
  key: [fs.readFileSync('./privkey.domain1.pem'), fs.readFileSync('./privkey.domain2.pem')],
  cert: [fs.readFileSync('./cert.domain1.pem'), fs.readFileSync('./cert.domain2.pem')],
  ca: [fs.readFileSync('./chain.domain1.pem'), fs.readFileSync('./chain.domain2.pem')],
}, (req, res) => { ... })
```

But got the following error:

```
Error: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

Answer (score 0):

This was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219639/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-return-an-ssl-certificate-in-nodejs#answer-20285934).

```js
var secureContext = {
  'subdomain1.example.com': tls.createSecureContext({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./privkey.domain1.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.domain1.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./chain.domain1.pem'),
  }),
  'subdomain2.example.com': tls.createSecureContext({
    key: fs.readFileSync('./privkey.domain2.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.domain2.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('./chain.domain2.pem'),  
  }),
};

options = {
  SNICallback: function (domain, cb) {
    if (secureContext[domain]) {
      if (cb) {
        cb(null, secureContext[domain]);
      } else {
        // compatibility for older versions of node
        return secureContext[domain];
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error('No keys/certificates for domain requested');
    }
  },
  key: fs.readFileSync('./privkey.domain1.pem'), // defaults are still required
  cert: fs.readFileSync('./cert.domain1.pem'), // defaults are still required
  ca: fs.readFileSync('./chain.domain1.pem'), // defaults are still required
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => { ... });
```