# How I can match the domain that cert is used for once I read them from a folder on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, ssl, https

In my application, I want to do the following:

```js
  const fs = require('fs');
  const { exit } = require('process');

  let https;
  try {
    https = require('node:https');
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('https support is disabled!');
  }
  
  const cert_dir = '/etc/myapp/certs';
  const secureContext = {}
  
  fs.stat(cert_dir,(err,cb) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        exit(-1);
    }

    fs.readdir(cert_dir,(err, files) => {
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            files.filter(item => {
                return path.extname(item)=='.cert'
            }).forEach(file => {
                console.log(file);
                const cert = path.join(cert_dir,file);
                const key = path.join(cert_dir,(path.basename(file,".cert")+".key"))

                fs.stat(key, (err, stat) => {
                    if(err == null){
                        const x509 = new X509Certificate(fs.readFileSync(cert));
                        console.log("cert Info",x509);

                        // get domain here
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });

  });

  const options = {
    SNICallback: function (domain, cb) {
        if (secureContext[domain]) {
            if (cb) {
                cb(null, secureContext[domain]);
            } else {
                // compatibility for older versions of node
                return secureContext[domain]; 
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error('No keys/certificates for domain requested');
        }
    },
    // must list a default key and cert because required by tls.createServer()
    key: fs.readFileSync('../path_to_key.pem'), 
    cert: fs.readFileSync('../path_to_cert.crt'), 
  };
  
  const server = https.createServer(options,handle);
  server.listen(449);
```

The `/etc/myapp/certs` contains the following content:

```
cert1.crt
cert1.pem
cert2.crt
cert2.pem
```

But according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38862651/4706711) I need some certificate - domain association. In my case though, I see no association. Is there a way to somehow guess the domain out of a certificate?

At line:

```
const x509 = new X509Certificate(fs.readFileSync(cert));
```

I want to be able to extract the domain out of a certificate.

Comment: As long as it is an X509 certificate, it contains the domain that is used. A relative example is: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-new-x509certificate-function/

Comment: Yes but offers no way to locate a domain out of a cert.