# Dynamically Assign SSL Certificates Based on Hostname in Node.js Reverse Proxy

Tags: node.js, http-proxy

I'm working on a Node.js reverse proxy that routes incoming requests to different backend applications based on the requested subdomain (hostname). I have two subdomains, 'random-1.example.com' and 'random-2.example.com,' each with its own SSL certificate. My goal is to dynamically select the appropriate SSL certificate based on the requested subdomain and route the request accordingly.

```
const express = require('express');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

// Define the ports for your backend applications
const backend1Port = process.env.APP1_PORT || 3000;
const backend2Port = process.env.APP2_PORT || 4000;

const backend1 = `http://localhost:${backend1Port}`;
const backend2 = `http://localhost:${backend2Port}`;

// Middleware for logging
app.use(morgan('dev'));

// Handle HTTP requests
app.all('*', (req, res) => {
  const host = req.headers.host;

  if (host === 'random-1.example.com') {
    console.log(`Request to ${host} forwarded to ${backend1}`);
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: backend1 });
  } else if (host === 'random-2.example.com') {
    console.log(`Request to ${host} forwarded to ${backend2}`);
    proxy.web(req, res, { target: backend2 });
  } else {
    // Handle requests for unknown hosts or other cases
    console.log(`Request to unknown host: ${host}`);
    res.status(404).send('Not Found');
  }
});

// Handle errors from the proxy
proxy.on('error', (err, req, res) => {
  console.error('Proxy error:', err);
  res.status(500).send('Proxy error');
});

// Load SSL/TLS certificates
const sslOptions = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl', 'private.key')),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl', 'certificate.crt')),
  ca: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'ssl', 'ca_bundle.crt')),
};

// Create an HTTPS server
const httpsServer = https.createServer(sslOptions, app);

// Listen on port 443 for HTTPS requests
httpsServer.listen(443, () => {
  console.log('HTTPS server is running on port 443');
});
```

The SSL Certficate files that I have was made for random-1.example.com domain. So even though random-2.example.com website loads just fine it shows that the ssl is not valid and the site is insecure. I know that I can just use a wildcard certificate which is more expensive. I was just wondering if I buy an SSL for random2.example.com would I be able to modify the code below in some way so that it could send the second ssl files?

Comment: If you use LetsEncrypt, either a wildcard cert _or_ a SAN cert for both domain1 and domain2 costs the same as a single-site cert, namely zero. However if you do have two (or more) different single-site certs, you can select among them **using SNICallback**; this is dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219639/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-return-an-ssl-certificate-in-nodejs/38862651#38862651 (from more than 10 years ago) and several more linked there.